# Purescript applicative does not execute

Tags: functional-programming, purescript

This executes:

```
main = do 
  ctx <- getCanvasElementById "stage" >>= getContext2D
  bs  <- initBranches
  tick 0 ctx bs
```

but this does not:

```
main = tick 0 <$> (getCanvasElementById "stage" >>= getContext2D)
              <*> initBranches
```

however both compile, and to my understanding both mean the same basic thing. Why is this the case? Can I use the applicative syntax here (its much more understandable imho)

---

this also works

```
main = do
  a <- (tick 0) <$> (getCanvasElementById "stage" >>= getContext2D) <*> initBranches 
  b <- a
  fprint b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
main = join $ tick 0 <$> (getCanvasElementById "stage" >>= getContext2D) 
                     <*> initBranches
```

the applicative creates a nested Eff, join resolves this easily